# Unable to update tidyr from 0.3.1 to 0.6.0

Tags: r, ubuntu, tidyr

I'm unable to update tidyr from 0.3.1 to 0.6.0. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.5.

I tried to update the package by running this code in RStudio:

```
update.packages("tidyr")
```

I didn't get any errors. I restarted RStudio and loaded tidyr using:

```
library(tidyr)
```

Here's my sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.1     data.table_1.10.0 tidyr_0.3.1       dplyr_0.4.3       plyr_1.8.3        MASS_7.3-44 
5  e  5 0 0 10
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Given that you figured things out on your own you should write what you did as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out the answer to this question -- I needed to update the Rcpp package.

I discovered the answer by running
    install.packages("tidyr")
This threw errors related to tibble and Rcpp which led me to this post: https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/169

After updating Rcpp, I was able to update tidyr.